# Clonezilla cannot restore image "Error! No existing disk(s) or no unmounted disk(s) are found!"

Tags: boot, partitioning, mount, backup

**What I am trying to do**:

I have a Ubuntu 20.04.02 LTS system and want to create an image that I can deploy on `n` machines that have the same hardware configuration as the system that served as the source of the image.

**What I am trying**:

I have created an image using clonezilla und sticking to the documentation provided on their site.
(Created a bootable USB device, booted that and copied the Ubuntu system's disc onto a partition of the USB device.)
No I have booted a new completely new device with the clonezilla USB device. Following the steps in the instructions I:

- Enter into `device-image` mode
- Enter into `local_dev` mode
- Select the USB device to mount it as `/home/partimag` and skip the check (there is no other device shown which makes me already think it does not read the connected SSD)
- Select the `/` directory for the image repository
- Enter `restoredisk` mode
- Choose the image I want to restore (it shows me the correct image I want to restore)

**Problem**:

Here it gives me the error message: "Error! No existing disk(s) or no unmounted disk(s) are found! To use Clonezilla to save or clone a disk, the source disk must exist or be unmounted! If you are sure the disk exists in this machine, maybe the kernel is too old?"

I am using Clonezille `alternative stable - 20210609-hirsute`.
Do I understand the situation correctly that clonezilla does not recognize the connected SSD so it does not know where to copy the image into? What can I do to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up. I have included the complete release version String as found in `lsb_release -a`

Comment: I have used Clonezilla (the alternative series based on Debian) for years, and it can recognize SSDs (via USB `/dev/sdx` as well as via PCI `/dev/nvme0n1`). Is this problem unique for one computer, or is it the same for all the computers, where you want to install Ubuntu? Have you checked if some other Linux live system, e.g. a live Ubuntu USB drive can recognize the target drive, where you want to install from the Clonezilla image?

Comment: @sudodus thank you for the comment. Tomorrow I will be able to test booting the new device with an Ubuntu live USB. I will post the results here.

Comment: @sudodus thank you for your advice. Finally some other devices have arrived and I could test the process with other devices, it was a hardware issue with the SSD disk. Everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

At the end the error message provided every piece of information that was needed.

> "Error! No existing disk(s) or no unmounted disk(s) are found! To use Clonezilla to save or clone a disk, **the source disk must exist or be unmounted**! If you are sure the disk exists in this machine, maybe the kernel is too old?"

The cable connecting the SSD to the main board was faulty, so the disk was not recognized. Using functional hardware and following the exact steps from the Clonezilla tutorial produces exactly the outcome that I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad that you found and solved the problem :-)